# Colorbox closing issue

Tags: html, colorbox

jQuery Colorbox not close after form submit and not redirected me to parent page. I want colorbox if form inputted data will be wrong.
I am calling login.html directly in colorbox.
My code is below.

Html Page One.

```
<ul>
  <li class="call-login-popup"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
              $(".call-login-popup").colorbox({
                  iframe: true,
                  width: 340,
                  height: 555,
                  inline: true,
                  scrolling: true,
                  href:"login.html",
                  });
            });
</script>
```

Html Page two login.html

```
<form id="login-form" action="demo.html" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" /><br/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass" /> <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use colorbox close after clicking submit button or after completing sending form

```
parent.jQuery.fn.colorbox.close();
```

So your code should be

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="Closepopup()"/>
function Closepopup(){
parent.jQuery.fn.colorbox.close();
}
```

or

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" id="closepopup"/>
$('#closepopup').click(function(){
parent.jQuery.fn.colorbox.close();
})
```